# How to create a custom splash screen for a program?

Tags: firefox, application-development, gtk3, window-decoration

I am currently building a client for our users at work with Ubuntu MATE 15.10 and Plank as a dock. But when I click for example the Firefox icon in the dock nothing happens until it suddenly pops up after >10 seconds, no loading icon as a mouse pointer or something like that.

Now is there a way to make a custom splash screen like the one in LibreOffice? Or just create a window like "Firefox is being started..."  which closes once the application is open?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Create a splash window

You can use `GTK`'s `gtk_window_set_decorated()` to create a splash window without (any) decorations. Combined with `gtk_window_set_position()`, you can pretty much create a custom splash screen.

An example

*(script1, the splash window)*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

class Splash(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="splashtitle")
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(maingrid)
        maingrid.set_border_width(80)
        # set text for the spash window
        label = Gtk.Label("Eat bananas while you are waiting for Firefox")
        label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 22'))
        maingrid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def splashwindow():
    window = Splash()
    window.set_decorated(False)
    window.set_resizable(False)  
    window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

splashwindow()
```

which creates a splash screen like:

[image]

Of course, you can set *any* background colour, font and fontsize, images etc, depending on your taste, but this is the basic idea.

#### Make the splash screen disappear if the application's window appears

To *kill* the splash screen once the application's window appears, you'll need a script to wait for the application window, and (indeed) kill the process that runs the window.

*(script2, the wrapper)*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# set the application below
application = "firefox"
# set the path to the splash script below
path = "/path/to/splash_screen.py"

subprocess.Popen([application])
subprocess.Popen(["python3", path])

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    try:
        pid = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", application]).decode("utf-8").strip()
        w_list = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8")
        if pid in w_list:
            splashpid = [l.split()[2] for l in w_list.splitlines()\
                         if "splashtitle" in l][0]
            subprocess.Popen(["kill", splashpid])
            break
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
```

#### How to use

1. The script (2) needs `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy script1 (the splash screen) into an empty file, save it as `splash_screen.py`. Change if you want the text for the splash screen (but why would you :) )

   ```
   label = Gtk.Label("Eat more bananas while you wait for Firefox")
   ```
3. Copy script2 into an empty file, save it as `splash_wrapper.py`
   In the head section of the script, change the path in the line:

   ```
   path = "/path/to/splash_screen.py"
   ```

   into the actual path (between quotes)
4. Now run the setup by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/splash_wrapper.py
   ```

   and your splash screen will appear if you run the wrapper, it will disappear once Firefox actually starts.

---

#### Notes

As mentioned the example above is quite straightforward. Of course you can make it much smoother, pimp the splash screen in all possible ways, or even make it semi- transparent:

[image]

*(code:)*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

class Splash(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="splashtitle")
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(maingrid)
        maingrid.set_border_width(80)
        # set text for the spash window
        label = Gtk.Label("Eat bananas while you are waiting for Firefox")
        label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 22'))
        maingrid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def splashwindow():
    window = Splash()
    window.set_decorated(False)
    window.set_resizable(False)
    window.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,1))
    window.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse("grey"))
    window.set_opacity(0.8)
    window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

splashwindow()
```

or include an image:

[image]

*(code:)*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, Pango

class Splash(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="splashtitle")
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(maingrid)

        image = Gtk.Image()
        # set the path to the image below
        image.set_from_file("/path/to/image.png")
        maingrid.attach(image, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        maingrid.set_border_width(40)
        # set text for the spash window
        label = Gtk.Label("Eat bananas while you are waiting for Firefox")
        label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 15'))
        maingrid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def splashwindow():
    window = Splash()
    window.set_decorated(False)
    window.set_resizable(False)
    window.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,1))
    window.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse("grey"))
    window.set_opacity(0.8)
    window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()

splashwindow()
```

and so on...

Furthermore, you can make the application and the text *arguments* of both scripts etc, but this is the basic idea.

#### No icon in Unity / tasklist?

If you do not want an icon to appear in Unity (or any other task manager, like Plank), you can simply add a line to the `__init__` section:

```py
self.set_skip_taskbar_hint(True)
```

Comment: Oh my god, thanks for this detailed explanation! I'll try it right tomorrow. And I guess the bananas are fine:D

Comment: @der_eismann added a more fancy (semi- transparent) version :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Great Answer. Is it possible to add webpage links in such window ? and/or also include a link which opens a txt file in an editor say gedit.

Comment: Wow!  Such a wonderful, detailed answer.  Thank you kindly!!